# Upgrade eclipse 4.4(Luna) to to 4.7(Oxygen)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2, update-site

I've updated Eclipse 4.4.2(Luna) to Eclipse Oxygen(4.7) using the update site http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7

But I can't launch the "eclipse" anymore - it shows the error "The application Eclipse can't be opened".

When I check eclipse package contents(in macOS) - "eclipse" executable name has changed to "launcher". And I was able to launch directly using "launcher" file

Since it's a broken change from Eclipse - how RCP products upgraded to their customers when they move their eclipse core version from 4.4 to higher versions.

**EDIT:**

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471702

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Issues_related_to_Mac_App_installations#Mars_Update_Warning

Here it's mentioned that "update" brings the "broken" installation and better to install a fresh version. I just wonder what else will be broken if you go by "update" mechanism.

I could see following are broken so far:

1. "eclipse" launcher file is missing
2. New eclipse oxygen installation directory layout is different compared with the what we get during the update. It didn't modify the dir structure when I updated from Luna to Oxygen

Love to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the [Mac OS X distribution as an Application Bundle since Eclipse Mars (4.5)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/platform.php#macapp).

All other issues are listed in

- the [Platform Plug-in Developer Guide - Plug-in Migration Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/nav/2_3) and
- the [JDT Plug-in Developer Guide - Plug-in Migration Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/nav/3_2).

Comment: Thanks @howlger. That's helpful.